# how to access custom Object parent in apex controller

Tags: apex, controller

Hi I am new to Apex coding and I was wondering if there was any way to get access to a parent Custom object from the Lead.

My Custom Obj has the field : Lead (Lookup(Lead))

In Apex I tried :

```
  global TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
  {
    ShouldRender = false;
    SObject entity = stdController.getRecord();
    Object test = entity.getSObject('Test_Object__c');
    System.debug('This is test ' + test);
  }
```

and it keeps on saying there is no relationship from lead to Test_Object__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to query to get the related object. You can also cast the standard controller reference to your type so you can directly reference its named fields:

```
global TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    ShouldRender = false;
    Test_Object__c t = (Test_Object__c) stdController.getRecord();
    if (t.Lead__c != null) {
        Lead l = [select Id, Name, ... from Lead where Id = :t.Lead__c];
        System.debug('t=' + t + ' l=' + l);
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming that the Lead is the "Parent" object as your custom object - I'm assuming that is Test_Object__c - has the lookup field but your question is a bit contradictory in that area. You can reverse Lead/Test_Object__c in the above code if the relationship is actually the other way round.)

**PS**

Based on the comment thread it is the Lead object that the standard controller is working with meaning that there can be zero to many Test_Object__c that reference that Lead so the code would look like this:

```
global TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    ShouldRender = false;
    Lead l = (Lead) stdController.getRecord();
    Test_Object__c[] ts = [
            select Id, Name, ...
            from Test_Object__c
            where Lead__c = :l.Id
            order by Name
            ];
    System.debug('l=' + l + ' ts=' + ts);
}
```

and in this case you are referencing the child objects from the parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really clarifies things. The Test_Object__c has a lookup field for Lead.

Comment: Can you explain the casting you did? It did not work for me because the controller is the context of a lead. I got the error

Invalid conversion from runtime type Lead to Test_Object__c

Comment: @James My misunderstanding. You can cast providing the type is right i.e. matches the standardController attribute in the apex:page. See the PS.